# If $x^2+x+1$ is composite, does always exist a $n$ such that $(n^2+n+1)|(x^2+x+1)$?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

I'm struggling to prove this proposition

> If $x^2+x+1$ is composite, then it exists an integer $n\neq x$ such that $(n^2+n+1)|(x^2+x+1)$

I've tried making substitutions,e.g, $x \rightarrow (p + 1)^2$ or $x \rightarrow -p^3+p^2+1$ that yields respectively
$${\left(p^{2} + 3 \, p + 3\right)} {\left(p^{2} + p + 1\right)}$$
$${\left(p^{4} - 3 \, p^{3} + 3 \, p^{2} - 3 \, p + 3\right)} {\left(p^{2} + p + 1\right)}$$

These families manifestly satisfy the proposition, but I don't know how to tackle the general case, i.e., for every $x$ where  $x^2+x+1$ is composite.

Comment: Since the proposition is false and you have been asked to prove it, may I ask where the question comes from?

Comment: @AdamRubinson What's wrong with $n=-1$?

Comment: True, I read it as, "positive integer", but you're correct; it doesn't actually say that in the question. But your observation means the question is trivial...

Comment: It was on an old problem sheet from my uni, perhaps there was a typo somewhere. It doesn't say much apart from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can find a counterexample when you test $x$ up to $30$.
(Apart from obvious situations like $ x \not \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ since otherwise $ 1^2 + 1 + 1 = 3 \mid x^2 + x + 1$,) There is no hard and fast rule about how to find counterexamples, so just test them all.

> $x = 26, x^2 + x + 1 = 703 = 19 \times 37$.

---

In general, there isn't a reason for that to happen for most (any non-linear?) polynomial.
Suppose the polynomial is $ \prod ( x - \omega_i)$.
Your claim is that as integers, $\prod ( x - \omega_i) = y_n \times \prod ( x_n - \omega_i)$.
In this form, there isn't a strong motivation for the claim. It is believable that for some $x$, we can split out the values $x - \omega_i$ in a different manner that doesn't require combining back into $\prod (x_n - \omega_i)$.

EG In the counter example, working in the Einstein integers where $ \omega = e ^{ \frac{ 2 \pi i } { 3} }$,

$$ \begin{array} {r l c l } 
& 26^2 + 26 + 1 \\
= & (26 - \omega) & \times & ( 26 + 1 + \omega)  \\
= & [( 2 - 3 \omega) ( 7 + 4 \omega)] & \times & [ (3 - 4 \omega )(5 + 3 \omega)   ]  \\
 = & [(2 - 3 \omega)(5 + 3 \omega)] & \times & [(7 + 4 \omega) ( 3 - 4 \omega) ] \\
 = & 19 & \times & 37 \end{array} $$

Note: Some of these terms could be factorized further so it doesn't necessarily mean that $19, 37 \neq n^2 + n + 1$. The idea is to provide an explanation of why your claim likely isn't true, because of how we can shift the factorization around.

---

Off the top of my head, I don't know which polynomials satisfy this property. The classic examples are $2n+1$ and $4n+3$.
Based on the above, I believe that it doesn't hold for non-linear polynomials, but I have no substantive proof of that. I would love to see a generalization.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful example! It's very clear. Perhaps the question wasn't well written in the problem sheet I got.